# PHP CURL call is displaying NULL all the time

Tags: php, curl

This question has been asked. But any of those didn't work out for me. I am getting NULL when CURL call is made all the time.

The following is my **list_clients.php** file.

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$clientResults  = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM clients");
$clients        = array();
while($client = mysqli_fetch_assoc($clientResults)){
    $clients[] = $client;
}
echo json_encode($clients);
exit;
```

So the output of the above is :

```
[{"ip_address":"192.168.177.137","mac_address":"3a:1a:cf:7c:92:89","added_on":"2017-08-19 12:48:34"},{"ip_address":"192.168.177.137","mac_address":"3a:1a:cf:7c:92:89","added_on":"2017-08-20 08:09:29"}]
```

The following is my **curl_call.php** file

```
<?php
$url    = 'http://127.0.0.1/testing/list_clients.php';
$curl   = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type : application/json',
                'Accept: application/json'
        ));
$clientResult   = curl_exec($curl);
if($clientResult == FALSE) {
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($clientResult); //For this line I am getting the following image eror

$clients        = json_decode($clientResult, TRUE);

var_dump($clients);
```

If I `var_dump($clientResult);` then I am getting the following error

[image]

It's displaying **NULL** all the time. What might be causing the error.

Comment: does the output of `$clientResult` is false or null ?

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump()` of `$clients` in your `list_clients.php` to make sure that it's not actually null?

Comment: Enable error reporting.

Comment: hi @hassan its returning the error I am attaching the image of that.

Comment: @NickCoons I have added the output of the list_clients.php file. Please check

Comment: May I know the reason for down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now figured out. If I comment the following line of code in the **curl_call.php** it will work fine.

```
<?php
$url    = 'http://127.0.0.1/testing/list_clients.php';
$curl   = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
/* curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type : application/json',
                'Accept: application/json'
        )); */
$clientResult   = curl_exec($curl);
if($clientResult == FALSE) {
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($clientResult);
$clients        = json_decode($clientResult);

var_dump($clients);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a warning being thrown about `$ch`.  It's undeclared, yet you reference it on line 17:

```
if($clientResult == FALSE) {
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
}
```

(As a side note, I'd use `=== FALSE`, so valid return values which cast to `FALSE` don't wrongly trigger that code.)

You're also then carrying on with execution after the error is (failed to be) handled.  The `NULL` you're seeing could be because the `curl` request failed.

Correct the typo in your code and stop (or do appropriately) if an error is thrown:

```
if($clientResult == FALSE) {
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
    exit();
}
```

---

**Update in response to the OP being updated**:

The other reason `NULL` might be returned is because the response is not valid `json`.  [Check the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values
>   true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL
>   respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the
>   encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

That HTML output you're debugging now shows (in your question update) won't parse as `JSON`.

Comment: Hi @wally its not because of that. By mistake while undoing I have posted it. Please check the edited question.

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari It'll be the non-JSON object you're trying to decode.

Comment: when I check in https://jsonlint.com/ it shows that its a valid json. Can you please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Your debug in the updated question showed Bad Request.  That's what you need to put through JSON lint.

Comment: let me edit my answer so that you will get to know where I am adding var_dump($clientResult);